# adding event listener to audio element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

i have made a simple music player and there is 2 events for it one for updating elapsed time and another for durationchange...elapsed time's function works fine but total time function doesn't...i have looked up in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp and durationchange is a standard event but i don't get it why it doesn't work. i also thought maybe the reason is that script is defined before label elements but moving scripts to the end of file didn't worked either.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCType HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    audio.id = "audio1"
    audio.src = "Music.mp3";
    audio.autoplay = true;
    window.onload = function () {
        audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', UpdateTheTime, false);
        audio.addEventListener('durationchange', SetTotal, false);

    }


    function UpdateTheTime() {
           var sec = audio.currentTime;
           var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
           sec = Math.floor(sec % 60);
           if (sec.toString().length < 2) sec = "0" + sec;
           if (min.toString().length < 2) min = "0" + min;
           document.getElementById('Elapsed').innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;


    }

    function SetTotal() {
        var sec = audio.duration;
        var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
        sec = Math.floor(sec % 60);
        if (sec.toString().length < 2) sec = "0" + sec;
        if (min.toString().length < 2) min = "0" + min;
        document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML = "/ " + min + " : " + sec;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/" id="player">
    <img src="Cover.jpg"/>
    <label id="Title">
    Imaginaerum
    </label>
    <label id="Artist">
    Nightwish
    </label>

        <label id="Elapsed">--:--</label>
        <label id="Total">/--:--</label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: w3schools is a terrible resource. Use MDN: [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video), [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case durationchange event fired before window.onload

```
        var audio; 
        window.onload = function () {
         audio= document.createElement("audio");
        audio.id = "audio1"
        audio.src = "Music.mp3";
        audio.autoplay = true;
            audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', UpdateTheTime, false);
            audio.addEventListener('durationchange', SetTotal, false);

        }


        function UpdateTheTime() {
               var sec = audio.currentTime;
               var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
               sec = Math.floor(sec % 60);
               if (sec.toString().length < 2) sec = "0" + sec;
               if (min.toString().length < 2) min = "0" + min;
               document.getElementById('Elapsed').innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;


        }

        function SetTotal() {
            var sec = audio.duration;
            var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
            sec = Math.floor(sec % 60);
            if (sec.toString().length < 2) sec = "0" + sec;
            if (min.toString().length < 2) min = "0" + min;
            document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML = "/ " + min + " : " + sec;
        }
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/rU7SU/

Comment: thanks...but internet explorer show wrong duration...in chrome duration is : 13:31 (Correct) but in internet explorer durations is 19:44 (wrong)...any one knows why this happens?